# How to access array data in laravel

Tags: laravel

I would like to access to a value from a array response but i get null or an exception "Trying to get property of non object"

here my array :

```
array:5 [▼
  677 => array:4 [▶]
  676 => array:4 [▶]
  675 => array:4 [▶]
  674 => array:4 [▶]
  673 => array:4 [▶]
]
```

I would like to get each id foreach items

```
array:5 [▼
  677 => array:4 [▼
    "qty" => 1
    "montant" => "25.00"
    "item" => Licencies {#961 ▼
      #table: "licencies"
      ...
      #attributes: array:46 [▶]
      #original: array:46 [▼
        "id" => 677
```

Here my actual controller

```
foreach ($items as $item) {

          $item = $item;

          dd($item);

      }
```

When i do $item = $item->id to get the id of the object i get "trying to get property of non object"

What should i do ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like `$item` is an array too. Try using the array syntax:

```
foreach ($items as $item) {

    $item = $item['id'];
}
```

Comment: Update your question with further details of your current problem.